# D3D_MIN_PRECISION не определён

Tags: c++, directx

Пишу приложение с использованием `DirectX SDK` на C++. Всё было нормально до того момента как я стал писать поддержку шейдеров в своём приложении. При сборке проекта выходит ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Догадываюсь, что это как-то связано с названием файла `d3d12shader.h`, обычно я не использовал `d3dx12`, а `d3dx11`. Может из-за совместимости или что-то вроде.

Ошибка ссылает меня на этот кусок кода `d3d12shader.h`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код приложения: https://pastebin.com/Zetad5y1

Comment: У вас подключен заголовочный файл `d3dcommon.h`? Именно в нём определены `D3D_INTERPOLATION_MODE`, `D3D_MIN_PRECISION ` и `D3D_PARAMETER_FLAGS`.

Comment: @Arhad В d3d11shader.h или в моих заголовках?

Comment: Во всех ваших заголовочных файлах, где используются эти типы.

Comment: Файл называется `D3d12shader.h`, откуда вы взяли `d3dx12shader.h`?

Comment: @Arhad `d3dcommon.h` включен в `D3d12shader.h`.

Comment: @VTT опечатался, сейчас исправлю

Comment: А вообще приведите минимальный код воспроизводящий проблему и ошибки в виде текста, а не картинки.

Comment: @Arhad  в d3d12shader он только используется

Comment: @VTT добавил код

Comment: В пост следует добавить *минимальный* пример кода, воспроизводящий ошибку. Не ссылкой, не картинкой, а текстом. И приведите полный текст ошибки. Опять же, не ссылкой, не картинкой, а текстом. См [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Где именно у вас подключен `d3dcommon.h`? В самом начале `d3d12shader.h`? Просто эта ошибка означает, что компилятор увидел использование перечисления до его объявления. Из кода же по ссылке ничего не понятно, так как там не проблемный заголовок, а какой-то `.cpp`-файл.

Comment: @Arhad не думаю, что проблема в самом заголовке. Про ошибку поподробнее можно? Я пробовал гуглить, и походу этого я делать не умею

Comment: Входе небольших тестов мне удалось узнать что проблема таится в двух инклюдах: `<xnamath.h>` и `<d3dcompiler.h>`. Узнал, что xnamath стоит заменить на `directxmath.h`. Корень же проблемы в d3dcompiler.h

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему убрав `include <d3dcompiler.h>` и заменив его на `#pragma comment(lib,"d3dcompiler.lib")`